# React native Android error on running the app

Tags: android, react-native

I'm trying to **build native code in my react native project** named AwesomeProject on Mac OS X El Capitan. 
Things work fine till **react-native init**.

Upon doing **react-native run-android** on the terminal, I get this error -

```
* What went wrong:
    A problem occurred configuring root project 'AwesomeProject'. >
    Could not resolve all dependencies
for configuration ':classpath'. >
    Could not resolve com.android.tools.build: transform - api: 2.0 .0 - deprecated - use - gradle - api.
Required by:
    : AwesomeProject: unspecified > com.android.tools.build: gradle: 2.2 .3 > com.android.tools.build: gradle - core: 2.2 .3 >
    Could not resolve com.android.tools.build: transform - api: 2.0 .0 - deprecated - use - gradle - api. >
    Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/transform-api/2.0.0-deprecated-use-gradle-api/transform-api-2.0.0-deprecated-use-gradle-api.pom'. >
    org.apache.http.ssl.SSLInitializationException: /Library/Java / JavaVirtualMachines / 1.6 .0.jdk / Contents / Home / lib / security / cacerts(No such file or directory) >
```

Do I need to install anything else ? Has anyone found this issue ?
If I try to use **gradle:2.2.3** on Android Studio to make a native Android app, it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like Using JDK 6 was the issue. I have now installed Java SE Development Kit 8 and it works fine. React native needs JDK 8 or more.